# What is mean by lazyVar in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Below is a code sample I don't understand what it means by lazyVar . Even I tried googling but I didn't get to see anything related to lazyVar. I came to see the lazy stuff, but not the lazyVar.

```
`
 @Test
    fun testLazyVar() {
        var testVar: String by lazyVar { "initial" }
        assertEquals("initial", testVar)
        testVar = "test"
        assertEquals("test", testVar)
    }`
```

Comment: I was just going through this repo over here https://github.com/renetik/renetik-android-core/tree/master. I also don't know the use of this repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a unit test named "test lazy var" so I would assume `lazyVar` is a function defined in this same project and this is where they are testing it. (It usually wouldn't make sense to write unit tests to test external library code.) You would have to browse through the project to find it. If you open the project in your IDE, you can Ctrl+Click it to jump to the code where it is defined.

---

Edit: I see that the project is a utility library named Renetik, containing functions and classes that the author believes would be useful for general Kotlin development. The `lazyVar` function and underlying class are defined [here](https://github.com/renetik/renetik-android-core/blob/master/library/src/main/java/renetik/android/core/lang/lazy/CSLazyVar.kt).

It is an alternative to the Kotlin standard library `lazy` delegate that supports using the delegate for a `var` property since `lazy` only supports `val` properties. It does not support disabling the thread-safety like `lazy` does.

The read-me for the library simply shows the unit tests for these functions as a way of showing exactly what they are supposed to accomplish. Perhaps the library is still new or the author doesn't have time to write documentation.